# How to split a string seperated by space in oracle and add each word to a different row in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, regexp-substr

I am trying to split a string and add each word to a separate rows.

```
with data as (
  select 100 as id, 'python java' as src from dual
)
 select id, level as lvl,
        regexp_substr( src || '" "' , '([[:space:]0-9/:])', 1, level, null, 1 ) as token
   from data
connect by level <= regexp_count( src || '" "' , '([[:space:]0-9/:])' )
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

I am expecting python and java in a separate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems a bit confused. I think you want something more like:

```
regexp_substr( src , '(.*?)([[:space:]0-9/:]|$)', 1, level, null, 1 )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70344ca4bac2d59639e77be0b7b722f6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `regexp_substr()` and `regexp_count()` with `connect by level<...` expression :

```
with t as
(
  select 100 as id, 'python java' as src from dual
)
 select id, level as lvl, regexp_substr(src, '[^[:space:]]+',1,level) as token
   from t 
connect by level<= regexp_count(src,'[[:space:]]')+1
    and prior id = id
    and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50809b3bc8b879fbf3e2574ea0107b5d)</kbd>